# Making an iframe take vertical space

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I would like to have an `iframe` take as much vertical space as it needs to display its content and not display a scrollbar. Is it at all possible ?

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should set the `IFRAME` height to its content's height:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
the_height = document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
document.getElementById('the_iframe').height = the_height;
</script>
```

You may want to add `scrolling="no"` to your `IFRAME` to turn off the scrollbars.

*edit:* Oops, forgot to declare `the_height`.

Comment: Very handy, cheers. Might be worth mentioning that this won't work so well if the iframe is on a different domain due to the same origin policy

Answer (score 0):

This CSS snippet should remove the vertical scrollbar:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I'm not sure yet about having it take up as much vertical space as it needs, but I'll see if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `DOCTYPE` declaration to the `IFRAME` source document will help to calculate the correct value from the line

```
document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
```

see [W3C DOCTYPE for examples](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

I was having problems with both IE and FF as it was rendering the `iframe` document in 'quirks' mode, until I added the `DOCTYPE`.

FF/IE/Chrome support: The .scrollHeight doesnt work with Chrome so I have come up with a javascript example using jQuery to set all `IFRAME` heights on a page based on the iframes content. NOTE: This is for reference pages within the your current domain.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('iframe').each(function(){
            var context = $(this);
            context.load(function(event){ // attach the onload event to the iframe  
                var body = $(this.contentWindow.document).find('body');
                if (body.length > 0 && $(body).find('*').length > 0) { // check if iframe has contents
                    context.height($(body.get(0)).height() + 20);
                } else {
                    context.hide(); // hide iframes with no contents
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is not to use `<iframe>` and preprocess code on server-side.

Comment: This isn't always possible, unless you're going to build a custom proxy server that rewrites links in the html body... which is a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out this thread: [How does the DiggBar dynamically resize its iframe's height based on content not on their domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754519/how-does-the-diggbar-dynamically-resize-its-iframes-height-based-on-content-not).

It addresses the same question.