# How to integrate site and iframe scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've been trying to integrate my site scrollbars with an iframe, it is, I need to include an iframe in my page, but I need to show only one scrollbar. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQXUC/2/

My goal is to have only **the outer** scrollbar in this example, it is, scroll the iframe site as part of my own page. I've found [some StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height) that help me understand how it works, but after a lot of tests I can't found any way to do it. Both jquery/javascript and CSS solutions are valid for me.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to have only my page scrollbar, no external site scrollbar. This is the same as say I don't want the user needs to scroll the iframe content :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

moz=document.getElementById&&!document.all 
mozHeightOffset=20 

function resize_iframe(){ 
document.getElementById("sizeframe").height=100 // required for Moz bug, value can be "", null, or integer 
document.getElementById('iframe_id').height=window.frames["iframe_name"].document.body.scrollHeight+(moz?mozHeightOffset:0) 
} 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<iframe width=300 id="sizeframe" name="sizeframe" src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="yes" onload=resize_iframe()></iframe>
```

Edit: I found this question: [Making an iframe take vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655/making-an-iframe-take-vertical-space) that has a simpler solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
the_height = document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
document.getElementById('the_iframe').height = the_height;
</script>
```

"You may want to add scrolling="no" to your IFRAME to turn off the scrollbars."